# How would I iterate an awaitMessages collector to collect multiple inputs as the loop increments?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, collectors

I am trying to create a setup command, where the user enters values which are then saved in an SQL db. However I am having trouble getting the `awaitMessages` method to wait within a for loop.

```js
let input = []; // declare input as empty array
    let setupQ = ['Please enter the role ID of admin', 'Please enter the role ID of mod', 'Please enter the ID of your log channel', 'Please enter the ID of your join/leave channel'];
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        message.channel.send(setupQ[i])   

        const filter = (user) => {
            return user.author.id === message.author.id 
        };
  
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
          .then(async collected =>  {
            input[i] = collected.first().content //takes user input and saves it
        }).catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
        });            
};
```

What currently happens, is that the bot immediately outputs the questions, without waiting for a user to reply. I have previously got this command to work, but by using 4 `awaitMessages` methods which were ugly and slow. (not to mention a formatting nightmare).

Can anyone see what I have to do to make it wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wait for each instruction execution use `await` inside an `async` function like `processStuff`.

This is actually a workaround to get a kind of **synchronous** execution (by the looks of it) in JS by leveraging it's **async paradigms**.

In the earlier code, creation of each of your Promise was not dependent on the previous one to be fully evaluated. But in this case, we're awaiting that promise creation.

```
let input = []; // declare input as empty array
    let setupQ = ['Please enter the role ID of admin', 'Please enter the role ID of mod', 'Please enter the ID of your log channel', 'Please enter the ID of your join/leave channel'];

async function processStuff(){
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        message.channel.send(setupQ[i])   

        const filter = (user) => {
            return user.author.id === message.author.id 
        };
        try{
        let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] });
           input[i] = collected.first().content; //takes user input and saves it
         } 
        catch(e)
         {
            message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
         }              
};
}

processStuff();
```

Conceptually this is equivalent to all of your 4 promises chained together (like `promise.then(...).then(...).then(...)`....) so that the creation of next promise (inside `then` callback of previous one) can only begin after the previous one got fully evaluated and returned a new promise.